# How to display Complete Evaluation Result in Echo Area itself in addition to new frame: Buffer > Message?

Tags: echo-area, message

I am new to Emacs and Emacs-Lisp. I have the following code:

```
(message "Her age is: %d" 10)
(message "Her name is: %s" "Nancy")
(message "My list is: %S" (list 7 4 2))
```

When I evaluate, it displays JUST the last line in the echo area.

```
My list is: 7 4 2
```

It does NOT display the first 2 lines.

Of course, on `C-h e` it displays all the 3 lines in **Buffer > *message*** area in new frame.

**Is there a way I can display ALL the 3 lines in echo area itself, in addition to message buffer frame, like the following?**

```
Her age is: 10
Her name is: Nancy
My list is: (7 4 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Emacs does display all 3 lines, but it displays them one by one, 
and each next `message` erases the previous one.
IOW, the echo area shows the result of the last command, and each command erases the previous output.

Try evaluating this:

```
(progn
  (message "Her age is: %d" 10)
  (sleep-for 1)
  (message "Her name is: %s" "Nancy")
  (sleep-for 1)
  (message "My list is: %S" (list 7 4 2))
  (sleep-for 1))
```

You will see all 3 messages one-by-one for 1 second each.

To see them all simultaneously, you need to use a single [`message`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/message.html) call:

```
(message "Her age is: %d\nHer name is: %s\nMy list is: %S" 
         10 "Nancy" (list 7 4 2))
```

Comment: Sir, is there a way I can see them all with different message calls? I mean, by way of adding some commands to .emacs file? So that Emacs does not erase the previous results.

Comment: @user16438: how do you imagine that? the echo area growing in size as you are using emacs? Pretty soon it will not fit your screen.

Comment: Sir, I tried this. Now, it just displays first and second line, one by one, for fraction of a second and goes off, and displays just the third line.there after. My question is: is there any configuration I can do to .emacs so that this work in normal way. Else, I will have to configure the Buffer screen. Am I right?

Comment: I am afraid you lost me. When you eval the last form in my answer, you do get all 3 lines, don't you?

Comment: Sir, The first line appear for ~1/3 of a second and disappear, then second line appear for ~1/3 of a second and disappear, then the third line appear and remain in the echo area.

Comment: yes, this is the correct behavior of the `progn` form (except that it should be 1 second instead of 1/3). If you do the last form (3-line `message`), the echo area grows in size to show all 3 lines. Try `(message "A\nB\nC")` in `emacs -Q`.